# Excel Macro: update sheet or create a new one based on a single criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want to write a macro which updates a single sheet out of many in an Excel workbook, based on a single criteria.

The first sheet of my workbook is titled *"Input"*; I copy and paste a client's portfolio into this blank sheet. Cell `A2` of *"Input"* contains the client's name.

The second sheet is titled *"Work"*; Column `I` of *"Work"* contains the client's data reorganized in the manner I need.

The rest of the sheets are named after specific clients (*"Jones, Matthew"* *"Smith, Peter"* etc.).

I want to create a macro which updates the sheet whose title matches the name contained in *"Input"* `A2`. Specifically, I want to copy Column `I` of *"Work"* and paste it in Column `A` of the sheet (ex. "Jones, Matthew") whose title matches *"Input"* `A2`.

I'd also like to have the macro create a new sheet if *"Input"* `A2` doesn't match the title of any of the existing sheets (i.e., if it is a new client). The text in *"Input"* `A2` should be the title of the new sheet (ex. *"Jones, Sarah"* ).

I would appreciate any advice on how to proceed. Unfortunately, my understanding of macros is very limited. I have tried to accomplish the task with simple formulas, but have so far been unsuccessful.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Post your macro thus far.

Comment: If you are not familiar with macros, Google "vba excel tutorials". The way I learned macros, before I studied computer science, was to record a macro, perform a task, and then study the vba code it produced. I read many how-to's and many websites. I've even came back to some workbooks, to date, and updated my vba code with more efficient methods now that I have experience in algorithms and code writing concepts. I've had lots of help here, but I always post my work and ask help for where I get "stuck".

Comment: A great help, in addition to @ejbytes excellent info, is after using the macro recorder, remove uses of `.Select`/`.Activate`.  [Here's a thread on how/why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: A formula might not be out of the question. Post some screenshots as it would be very helpful in visualizing your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the macro that you need.

```
 Public Sub clients()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks, wks1, wks2 As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    nwks = wkb.Sheets.Count 'Number of sheets on the Workbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets("Input")
    clientname = wks.Cells(2, 1) 'Name of the client on cell A2 of Input
    If clientname <> "" Then 'if clientname is not empty
        found = False
        For i = 1 To nwks
            sheetname = wkb.Sheets(i).Name
            If sheetname = clientname Then found = True 'sheet exists
        Next i
        If found = False Then 'If sheet doesn't exist then create it
            With wkb
                Set wks1 = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
                wks1.Name = clientname
            End With
        End If
        'Copy column I from work to client name column A
        Set wks1 = wkb.Sheets("Work")
        Set wks2 = wkb.Sheets(clientname)
        wks1.Columns(9).Copy wks2.Columns(1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Open VBA/Macros with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, under *ThisWorkbook* insert a new module and paste the code on the right side.

Execute it clicking the green triangle.

I put comments on the code to let you understand how it works.

You can run it also step by step by clicking on the first line and then go through each step pressing <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Comment: This is amazingly helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Corey Although we don't promote free script writing services... were you able to follow this example? It encompasses "for loops". Another thing to look into is "foreach element" loops which works great with "arrays" and "ranges"; something else to look into when entering the world of programming basics. Arm yourself with knowledge :)

Comment: Would it be necessary to define/declare, found, nwks, and clientname as: Dim found As boolean and Dim nwks As Integer and Dim clientname, sheetname as String? Or does VBa allow new var's without first declaring them? I decided to look this up while asking the question. I found this, midway of my thoughts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205560/excel-vba-variable-declaration-necessary

Comment: Variables (integer, boolean, string, etc.)don't need to be declared. Objects like workbooks, worksheets, ranges need to be declared.

Comment: I was finding this task to be overwhelming on my own, so it was a huge help to have @jcbermu 's text to look at line by line and work off of.

Comment: Another question - is there a way to paste only the values of the cells in the last step:

wks1.Columns(9).Copy wks2.Columns(1)

?

Comment: Yes. You have to split that line in two lines: **First:**  `wks1.Columns(9).Copy` and **second:** `wks2.Columns(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.